# Copy one directory to another in same amazon s3 bucket

Tags: php, codeigniter, amazon-s3

I am working with codeigniter. For Amazon I have used its library.

I need to rename a directory in an Amazon S3 bucket.

For that I used to copy one directory to another directory and the delete old directory after the copy, because I didn't get a direct way to rename the folder.

I have used this code :

```
$ci->s3->copyObject(
$ci->config->item("BUCKET"),  //bucket name
$originalPath . $csrf,  //source folder
 $ci->config->item("BUCKET"), //bucket name
$originalPath . $productId) //destination folder
```

But this is not working to **copy** one directory to another.

Please show me the correct way to rename a folder.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this to **move** files from one folder to an existing other with the [awscli](https://aws.amazon.com/cli/):

```
aws s3 mv s3://your_bucket/old_folder/ s3://your_bucket/new_folder/ --recursive
```

If you want to copy the files change `mv` to `cp`.

Please be aware that your `old_folder` will not be deleted. It just will be empty after all files have been moved.